# Smart way to handle before_save rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, exception, callback

I want to send sms, if my model is created. If it's not (for whatever reason) I don't want to send it. Here is the bit that sends sms :

```
def some_method
  TWILIO_CLIENT.account.sms.messages.create(
    :from => self.from,
    :to => self.to,
    :body => self.body
  )
end
```

So initially I thought to put the callback :

```
after_create :some_method
```

But then my model would be saved and what happens when `some_method` produces exception, in that case the model still gets saved to the db.

So I changed it to validation :

```
validate :some_method
```

So this way I'm thinking now, I can do this :

```
def some_method
  begin
     TWILIO_CLIENT.account.sms.messages.create(
          :from => self.from,
          :to => self.to,
          :body => self.body
        )
  rescue
     errors.add(:base, "Error message")
  end
end
```

So in this case, when the exception occurs during the sending of the sms it will prevent my model instance to be saved right?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Also if some other validation fail before `some_method` validation, will this one still be executed? (I don't want to send sms if the validation failed elsewhere)

**Question update:**

How can I make it all work together. Rollback if sending sms fails, or if object doesn't save for some reason that I don't send sms. But only and only if object is saved that I send sms?

**Another update: (what I ended up doing)**

```
class MyKls
  before_create :some_method

  def self.create_from_user_params(user)
    some_kind_of_pin_generation = 1231312    

    MyKls.create({
      :body => "Code is: #{some_kind_of_pin_generation}",
      :from => TWILIO_NUMBER,
      :to => user.phone, 
      :pin => some_kind_of_pin_generation,
      :user_id => user.id
    })
  end

  def some_method
    TWILIO_CLIENT.account.sms.messages.create(
      :from => self.from,
      :to => self.to,
      :body => self.body
    )

    rescue Twilio::REST::RequestError
      return false
  end
end
```

So here is the strange bit :

When I try to create `MyKls` instance with wrong format phone to cause exception like :

```
MyKls.create(:to => 'blabla', ...someotherargs...)
```

Causes rollback because it invokes exception and its successfully caught by the rescue in the `after_create` callback.

However if I use class method `MyKls.create_from_user_params(user)` the instance is always saved no matter the format of users phone.

Why is that?

It works for above create but it doesn't work for class method which internally invokes create?

When I set the wrong format phone to `MyKls` instance so it would cause the twilio exception.

Comment: It will still send an sms if some other validation is failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a `before_create` ... if it returns false the create will be rolled back

```
before_create :some_method

def some_method
   TWILIO_CLIENT.account.sms.messages.create(
        :from => self.from,
        :to => self.to,
        :body => self.body
      )
  return true
rescue
  return false
end
```

(note that you don't need a BEGIN / END if you're using a rescue in a method)

You may need to test in your controller if object.persisted? to test if the save was successful....

Comment: thanks for your answer. But this doesn't work for some reason. I have a class method that creates the instance i.e MyModel.create_from_params(params). And after the instance has been created and should have fail and end up in rescue part it didn't. However if I did MyModel.create(params) then it failed and ended up in rescue block as expected

Comment: Huh! Interesting. Thanks for the clarification. I'll try it from my end and see where I went wrong.

Comment: I can't replicate this.  If I create a class method `create_from_user_params` which calls the `create` class method and I set up a `before_create` callback that's designed to fail (e.g. `def some_method; 5 / 0; true ; rescue ; false ; end`) then I see the roll back.

Comment: that's odd I replaced body of my callback method `some_method` with `5/0` to make it fail, still doesn't fail with class method. How odd..

Comment: changed the method name, all works just fine. weird. thanks for your answer I'll accept